# What does further up the train mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases

In this sentence, what is the meaning of **further up the train**?

> I did not see the lady again until the following day, when both she and I got on the next train from Dresden to Ruritania. She was **further up the train**, however, and did not see me.

Comment: Have you tried searching it up first?

Comment: yes but I didn't find a definition for it

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: "I did not see the lady again until the following day, when both she and I got on the next train from Dresden to Ruritania. She was further up the train, however, and did not see me."

Comment: It means she was in a train car attached nearer to the front of the train.

Answer (score 8):

"Further up" quite literally means *higher*; it is very frequently used to indicate that something is "closer to the top"  (as in *further up the mountain*).  In cases where the object being referenced is horizontal, the "top" of the object will be its head or front.
  In the case of a train (clearly a horizontal object), the front is the engine; *further up the train* is therefore somewhere closer to the engine.

Comment: I would not say it was that specific as to indicate nearer or further from the engine. The speaker could be using it in refereance to the direction they were heading or facing. eg. if the platform entrance was at the front of the train, further up the train could refer to being nearer to the back.

Comment: @JamesRyan, I expect most people in that case would say "further down".

Comment: Maybe that emphasis is regional, you certainly couldn't count on it. In my experience people use 'further up' as a direct replacement for 'further along' with no added implication.

Answer (score 4):

Look up this meaning of ***further up*** in the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/further):

> 2.1 **Beyond the point already reached or the distance already covered:**
>
> *Amelie decided to drive further up the coast*

In the given context:

> She was further up the train, however, and did not see me.

The sentence implies that the lady was towards the beginning (so to speak) of the train, ie. near the engine. That's why "*further up the train*" is used.